# Paste lagging values into collapsed string/vector

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I take lagging values of a column, and vectorize the pasting of values into a string?

For example, assuming the following data frame, the result would be column 'lagged'

```
     date             total_volume      lagged
     <date>           <int>             <chr>
     2017-01-01       323512            323512
     2017-01-02        28014            323512, 28014
     2017-01-03        12323            323512, 28014, 12323
     2017-01-04        11580            323512, 28014, 12323, 11580
     2017-01-05        12161
     2017-01-06        10796
     2017-01-07        10087
     2017-01-08        10406
     2017-01-09        11261
     2017-01-10        11333
```

I tried using the approach:

```
df %>% 
 mutate(lagged = paste(total_volume[1:row_number()], collapse = ','))
```

but that returns an error.  I can create a function that loops and creates it, but when using the function in dplyr, it does not work correctly.

```
function(x) {
 for (i in 1:nrow(x)){
  print(paste(x$total_volume[1:i], collapse = ','))
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Reduce` function with `accumulate=T`, which applies the `paste` recursively:

```
df %>% mutate(lagged = Reduce(function(i,j) paste(i,j,sep=","),total_volume,accumulate=T))
```

This returns:

```
        date   total_volume                                                      lagged
1  2017-01-01       323512                                                       323512
2  2017-01-02        28014                                                 323512,28014
3  2017-01-03        12323                                           323512,28014,12323
4  2017-01-04        11580                                     323512,28014,12323,11580
5  2017-01-05        12161                               323512,28014,12323,11580,12161
6  2017-01-06        10796                         323512,28014,12323,11580,12161,10796
7  2017-01-07        10087                   323512,28014,12323,11580,12161,10796,10087
8  2017-01-08        10406             323512,28014,12323,11580,12161,10796,10087,10406
9  2017-01-09        11261       323512,28014,12323,11580,12161,10796,10087,10406,11261
10 2017-01-10        11333 323512,28014,12323,11580,12161,10796,10087,10406,11261,11333
```

Comment: Thank you! Accepted

Answer (score 0):

I figured out you can also call accumulate directly.

Here's what I came up with, which works with grouping's (ie:  the accumulate is reset at the beginning of a new group):

```
df %>%
group_by(group) %>%
mutate(lagged = accumulate(total_volume, paste, collapse = ',')
```